# Find words with the highest proportion of a single letter

Tags: word, english, open-ended, language, letters

Thanks to JoeZ, pacoverflow, isaacg, Sp3000, Novarg, Ram, h34, and all those who contributed answers that have since been beaten. I've accepted JoeZ's answer since he has the most mentions on the list below, but this puzzle isn't 'closed': if you can beat any of the words on the list below, post an answer and your name will be mentioned!

---

### The challenge

For each letter of the alphabet, A to Z, **find a word containing the highest possible proportion of that letter** If people come up with more than one word with the same proportion, **the longest one wins**.

Examples:

- taking the letter A, the best I can think of is "taramasalata" (6/12), which trumps "banana" (3/6) because it's longer; "banana" in turn trumps "razzmatazz" (3/10), although the latter word might be a good candidate for the letter Z
- taking the letter B, "blubber" (3/7) is an easy starting point which can probably be outdone.

Rules:

- only words of at least 5 letters
- no proper nouns (i.e. place or person names)
- only English dictionary words
- exclude words like "aaaaaah" and "hmmmmmm" which could in theory be extended as far as you like to get arbitrarily many A's or M's

Hopefully this covers all the loopholes, so that nobody will come up with 'silly' examples that need more rules to avoid!

This is an [open-ended](/questions/tagged/open-ended) puzzle, which means the current best answer may be outdone at any time. Partial answers (not covering all 26 letters) are fine; you can make them cover all 26 just by copying from the "current best" which I'll keep updated below.

---

### Current best

A: **araara** (4/6) [credit: **TakingNotes**]
B: **bobby** (3/5) [credit: **pacoverflow**]
C: **coccic** (4/6) [credit: **isaacg**]
D: **dodded** (4/6) [credit: **isaacg**]
E: **peewee** (4/6) [credit: **Joe Z**]
F: **feoff** / **fluff** (3/5) [credit: **Sp3000** / **isaacg**]
G: **glogg** (3/5) [credit: **Joe Z**]
H: **hashish** (3/7) [credit: **isaacg**]
I: **iiwis** (3/5) [credit: **h34**]
J: **hajji** (2/5) [credit: **Sp3000**]
K: **kakkak** (4/6) [credit: **isaacg**]
L: **lulls** / **lolls** / **lolly** (3/5) [credit: **Joe Z** / **isaacg** / **Novarg**]
M: **mommy** / **mamma** / **mummy** (3/5) [credit: **pacoverflow** / **isaacg** / **Novarg**]
N: **nanny** (3/5) [credit: **pacoverflow**]
O: **voodoo** / **booboo** (4/6) [credit: **Joe Z** / **Sp3000**]
P: **peppy** / **puppy** / **pappy** / **poppy** (3/5) [credit: **pacoverflow** / **Novarg** / **Sp3000** / **Joe Z**]$^1$
Q: **duqqa** (2/5) [credit: **TakingNotes**]
R: **rarer** / **error** (3/5)  [credit: **pacoverflow** / **isaacg**]
S: **assess** / **sasses** (4/6) [credit: **Joe Z** / **pacoverflow**]
T: **tatty** (3/5) [credit: **Sp3000**]
U: **muumuu** (4/6) [credit: **Joe Z**]
V: **vivid** / **divvy** / **valve** / **civvy** (2/5) [credit: **pacoverflow** / **isaacg** / **Novarg** / **Sp3000**]
W: **powwow** (3/6) [credit: **Joe Z**]
X: **xerox** (2/5) [credit: **Joe Z**]
Y: **syzygy** (3/6) [credit: **Joe Z**]
Z: **pzazz** (3/5)

At the moment I'm listing ties, but please don't go too much over the top with new words that match old ones - if there get to be too many equal winners for each letter, I'll have to remove all but the first one.

<sub>$^1$ Nobody mention "pippy"! :-)</sub>

Comment: Couldn't you just run a dictionary search?

Comment: @JoeZ. I'm hoping this will be an interesting challenge rather than just a "who's got the biggest dictionary"-type thing!

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not computer-searching through a dictionary while coming up with the words in my list.

Comment: is *Mississippi* a proper noun?

Comment: bubble , 3/6 for B should trump blubber (3/7)

Comment: _Indivisibility_ for the letter _i_: `6/14 = 3/7` beats `1/3`

Comment: @Narmer Nice one, but *bikini* is even better!

Comment: _iiwis_ beats _bikini_, and _qaimaqam_ beats _equivoque_ and _quinquina_.

Comment: _Quinque_ is an English prefix and can be quoted from Latin (e.g. when referring to the [quinque viae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinque_viae)), but do any dictionaries list it as an actual loanword? _Pzazz_ is in the OED.

Comment: Is supercalifrag... considered a word?

Comment: @Narmer and indivisibilities would be 7/16

Comment: V -> Vive (2/4),
T -> Tit (2/3) and
P -> Pip (2/3)
I think it's good enough

Comment: @Francesco Unfortunately one of the rules is "only words of at least 5 letters".

Comment: Does "Katana" (Sword) count?

Comment: @user9214072 Yes, but "katana" (3/6) has already been beaten by "agama" (3/5).

Comment: I see, @RandAlThor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles). (This is a bit textbook open-ended, since it keeps getting bumped with new answers and no answer can guarantee optimality)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My contributions to this list:

B: hubbub (3/6)
C: coccyx (3/6)
E: peewee (4/6)
G: glogg (3/5)
I: radii (2/5)
J: jejune (2/6)
L: lulls (3/5)
O: voodoo (4/6)
P: poppy (3/5)
Q: equivoque (2/9, had to google for this one)
S: assess (4/6)
U: muumuu (4/6)
V: vulva (2/5)
W: powwow (3/6)
X: xerox (2/5, if we're counting genericized trademarks)
Y: syzygy (3/6)
Z: pizzazz (4/7)

Also some sketchy and dubious contenders:

E: teevee (4/6, a transcribed phonetic spelling of TV [OED])
O: hoooo (4/5, a Japanese loan word for phoenix, also spelled houou)
T: tut-tut (4/6, a hyphenated interjection expressing disapproval [OED])

Comment: You might have a better time asking for the highest letter *ratio*, not counting words that are just a single letter repeated.

Comment: Highest ratio was actually my original idea, but then I thought ... most of the highest-ratio words will actually be really short ones like "bib" or "too", which makes it not so interesting.

Comment: True. Maybe highest ratio with at least five letters?

Comment: That's a good idea, but why five rather than four or six? Maybe I'll do that ... do you think it's OK to edit the question? Only 7 views ... probably nobody will notice if I edit!

Comment: Yeah, at this point only I've answered, and I'm okay with the question change.

Comment: Five just because it's an odd number, I guess.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question. I think *pzazz* (3/5) is a word too, beating *pizzazz*.

Comment: pzazz would win by about 2.8%, yes. Is it a word in the dictionary?

Comment: [Seems to be](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pzazz). You're almost filling in from the bottom up! :-)

Comment: The bottom ones are just more familiar to me.

Comment: With the new objective, your super-long I and O words aren't much use. Any 5-letter word with two O's will beat that 45-letter monstrosity. "Hoopoe" has 50% O's.

Comment: I've already changed them. :P

Comment: I don't think the Xerox Corporation would be too happy with you claiming that their trademark--which they work very hard to protect--has been genericized.

Comment: Well, until the Xerox Corporation decides to send me a cease and desist order for this answer, I think I'll let it slide.

Answer (score 7):

A: alpaca (3/6)
B: bobby (3/5)
C: cocky (2/5)
D: added (3/5)
F: fifty (2/5)
G: gagged (3/6)
I: idiom (2/5)
K: kicks (2/5)
M: mommy (3/5)
N: nanny (3/5)
P: peppy (3/5)
R: rarer (3/5)
S: sasses (4/6)
T: tattle (3/6)
V: vivid (2/5)

Comment: "alpaca" is already beat out by taramasalata, though.

Answer (score 4):

I: [isidioid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/isidioid) or [kivikivi](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Kivikivi) (4/8).

Comment: Thanks and +1, but h34 has now beaten 4/8 with "iiwis"!

Answer (score 4):

My attempt

Q - quinque is 2/7 (five/having five)

Sorry I completely forgot these don't qualify due to five letter minimum

V - vav is 2/1 (I guess it may not qualify as its a letter of the Hebrew alphabet)
V - viva/vive is 2/4 (long live)

Comment: Thanks! I've used up my vote limit for the day, but will upvote after midnight :-)

Comment: Is *quinque* really a word?  The dictionaries I’ve checked (the [OED](http://www.oed.com) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com)) do list it, but only as a combining form (i.e. as a prefix in words like *quinquefoliate*, “having five leaves”) not as a standalone word.

Answer (score 4):

for the word with the highest h ratio you could do HIGHTH 3/6

Comment: how has this not replaced `hashish (3/7)` yet?

Answer (score 3):

Some more contributions:

A: agama  (3/5)
C: cocci  (3/5)
F: feoff  (3/5)
J: hajji  (2/5)
T: tatty  (3/5)

Everything else I got tied with Joe and pac's answers.

One for "x" that's not a trademark (although "xerox" is pretty common):

X: maxixe (2/6)

*Edit*: Since we seem to be doing ties, here are the tied answers I got which were different:

O: booboo    (4/6)
P: pappy     (3/5)
Q: quinquina (2/9)
V: civvy     (2/5)

---

Deemed invalid:

H: highth (3/6)
I: filii  (3/5)

Comment: People [above](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10557/find-words-with-the-highest-proportion-of-a-single-letter?noredirect=1#comment31837_10565) thought maybe "highth" should be excluded as obsolete. Also "filii" is a bit dodgy because it's Latin!

Comment: Is "lilly" a dictionary word? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: @randal'thor Oops sorry. My dictionary has proper nouns in it and I've been checking each one, but I thought `lilly` was the flower and neglected to do so for that one.

Answer (score 3):

Current best list, as far as I know:

a: agama, 3/5
b: bobby, 3/5
c: coccic, 4/6
d: dodded, 4/6
e: peewee, 4/6
f: fluff, 3/5
g: glogg, 3/5
h: hashish, 3/7
i: bikini, 3/6
j: hajji, 2/5
k: kakkak, 4/6
l: lolls, 3/5
m: mamma, 3/5
n: nanny, 3/5
o: voodoo, 4/6
p: peppy, 3/5
q: equivoque, 2/9
r: error, 3/5
s: assess, 4/6
t: tatty, 3/5
u: muumuu, 4/6
v: divvy, 2/5
w: powwow, 3/6
x: xerox, 2/5
y: syzygy, 3/6
z: pzazz, 3/5

Recent updates:

- Added "pzazz", which is arguably valid.

Comment: "highth" is a word? I always assumed it was "heigth" and just a misspelling of "height".

Comment: Wikipedia says it's obsolete - I'll remove it.

Comment: Equivoque is 2/9, not 1/5.

Comment: Also powwow is 3/6.

Comment: @JoeZ. A lot of the fractions were wrong. I think they're fixed now.

Comment: "kayak" is more common than "kapok".

Comment: @JoeZ. and "kicks" is more common still - I'll use that.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not counting "glogg"? 3/5 > 4/7.

Comment: @JoeZ. Yeah, it  didn't seem to have a definition, so I didn't count it.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glogg)

Comment: "filii" seems to be Latin; I'm not sure whether we should count that!

Comment: FWIW, the word with the highest ratio so far is _hoooo_ with 4/5, and in equal second place, all with 4/6, are _coccic_, _dodded_, _peewee_, _teevee_, _kakkak_, _poopoo_, _voodoo_, _assess_, _sasses_ and _muumuu_.

Comment: @h34 If Pokémon names were allowed, we could get 4/5 for "Eevee".

Comment: Obsolete words clearly aren't an issue: https://cutt.ly/vzXDx9B (Google ngram)

Answer (score 3):

Based on current best I made this list:

A: agama (3/5)
B: baobab (3/6)
C: cancer (2/6)
D: daddy (3/5)
E:
F: fluff (3/5)
G: gagging (4/7)
H: height (2/6)
I: bikini (3/6)
J:
K: kukri (2/5)
L: lolly (3/5)
M: mummy (3/5)
N: cannon (3/6)
O:
P: puppy (3/5)
Q: queue (1/5)
R: horror (3/6)
S: possess (4/7)
T: twitter (3/7)
U:
V: valve (2/5)
W:
X:
Y:
Z:

Couldn't think about any words that can beat **E, J, O, U, W, X, Y, Z**. Other words are better that current best (at least for now)

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, since I mentioned this in comments but haven't seen it in anyone else's answer:

> Z: [**pzazz**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pzazz) (3/5)

Answer (score 3):

For s, obsessivenesses would work if you allow plurals. If not, then obsessiveness is still good!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! "Assess" was already posted, and it has 4/6 letters "s" - "obsessivenesses" has 6/15, which is much smaller.

Answer (score 3):

My contributions (many duplicates and ties with others--alas no new champions):

a:  Kabaa (3/5)
b:  bobby (3/5)
c:  cocci (3/5)
d:  added (3/5)
e:  peewee (2/3)
f:  faffs (3/5)
g:  gagging (4/7)
h:  hashish (4/7)
i:  bikini (1/2)
j:  hajji (2/5)
k:  Akkad (2/5)
l:  lolls (3/5)
m:  mammy (3/5)
n:  nanny (3/5)
o:  boohoo (2/3)
p:  pappy (3/5)
q:  aquas (1/5)
r:  error (3/5)
s:  assess (2/3)
t:  tatty (3/5)
u:  muumuu (2/3)
v:  bevvy (2/5)
w:  bowwow (1/2)
x:  Exxon (2/5)
y:  byway (2/5)
z:  pzazz (3/5)

In *Mathematica*:

```
alllongwords = Select[DictionaryLookup[___], StringLength[#] > 4 &];
letterratiolists = 
  Table[((StringCount[#, CharacterRange["a", "z"][[qq]]]/
        StringLength[#]) & /@ alllongwords), {qq, 1, 26}];
Table[alllongwords[[Position[letterratiolists[[qq]], 
     Max[letterratiolists[[qq]]]][[1, 1]]]], {qq, 1, 26}]
```

Here are the results in Spanish:

```
{"abada", "baobab", "cicca", "dedada", "berebere", "afufa", "galga", 
"huchohó", "dividivi", "ajajá", "kappa", "alcall", "súmmum", 
"nengún", "ojoso", "cappa", "quique", "errar", "esposas", "tatetí", 
"chucuru", "valva", "aarónica", "coxcox", "yarey", "cazuz"}
```

and French:

```
{"agaça", "baobab", "accroc", "dadas", "exerce", "fieffé", "gigogne",
"chahs", "infini", "joujou", "kakis", "libellule", "summum", "nanan",
"rococo", "appas", "qqu'un", "errer", "assis", "attentat", "cumulus",
"aviva", "clown", "anxieux", "youyou", "lazzi"}
```

and Italian:

```
{"agata", "babbi", "cacca", "addendi", "aeree", "baffi", "aggeggi",
"chicche", "finii", "abate", "quark", "lilla", "mamma", "nonna",
"odono", "pappa", "qualunque", "correr", "sassi", "tatti", "usufruì",
"evviva", "Newton", "Morgex", "Cluny", "zazzera"}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which records you've beaten?

Answer (score 2):

Does secessionists (5/13) qualify?

#### Edit

I know this won't qualify to win, but I found one with five s with a better ratio

assessments (5/11)

Comment: Yes, but it's already outdone by "assess" and "sasses".

Comment: So you are validating through the ratio not the number of repeating letters?

Comment: That's right. From the OP: "find a word containing the *highest possible proportion* of that letter".

Answer (score 1):

S: **sass's** / **sess's** / **siss's** / **suss's** (4/5)

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but, any pokemon fans ? :)

Eevee ( 4 / 5 )

And also:

Atacama ( 4 / 7 ) 'a desert in Chile'
Scissors ( 4 / 8 )
Milli-millillion ( 6 / 15 )
riffaff ( 4 / 7 )
protozoology ( 5 / 12 )
stresslessness ( 7 / 14 )

Answer (score 0):

a: abaca, 3/5
b: bibbs, 3/5
e: beebee, 4/6
j: jujus, 2/5
l: allyl, 3/5
o: coocoo, 4/6
p: pappi, 3/5
s: sisses, 4/6

Answer (score 0):

Current records:

A - araara (4/6) ~ New Zealand jargon for trevally
Q - duqqa (2/5) ~ an Egyptian spice
P - poppop (4/6) ~ informal term for grandfather (not validated yet)

Invalid suggestions:

A - laalaa (4/6) ~ a Senegalese language

Links: [araara](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/araara), [duqqa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duqqa), [poppop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pop-pop#Alternative_forms) (it's listed under alternate forms), [laalaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laalaa_language)

Comment: Laalaa is a proper noun, I suppose. Duqqa is valid.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Added a hopefully more valid word for the A, hope this one works.

Answer (score 0):

B: BLABBY (3/6)

E: GREEGREE (4/8)

G: GIGGING (4/7)

L: BELLPULL (4/8)

M: HAMMAM (3/6)

O: BOOCOO (4/6)

P: POPPER (3/6)

S: CLASSLESSNESSES (7/13)

Comment: None of these beat the already existing answers for those letters.

Answer (score -1):

My contributions:

a - maharaja (4/8)
b -
c -
d -
e - eyelevel (4/8)
f - riffraff (4/8)
g - giggling (4/8)
h -
i - indivisibilities (7/16)
j - juju (2/4)
k - kabaka (3/6)
l -
m - **muumuu was already done. :/**
n -
o -
p -
q -
r - extraterrestrial (4/16)
s -
t - extraterrestrial (3/16)
u -
v -
w -
x -
y -
z -

Comment: None of these beat the current ratios except `juju`, which is invalid according to the rules.

Comment: @Deusovi Sorry. Forgot about the 5-letter rule. And I don't care if they don't beat.